# Arrange the multi-similar data efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

The datafile showed here is the measuring record exported from instrument.

I uploaded it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7FE0kxAL8kQSmxoMEhHUjV0VUk/view?usp=sharing), anyone interested can download it.

#### Background

```
Sample
RECORD-1
FID1, FID2, front_temperature, laser, laserlow, pressure, mode
-925    284 1452    315 143 16653   He  -28500
-924    281 1462    322 136 16641   He  -28628
-920    281 1455    311 139 16649   He  -28756
-923    279 1454    312 139 16636   He  -28884
......

Sample
RECORD-2
FID1, FID2, front_temperature, laser, laserlow, pressure, mode
-925    284 1452    315 143 16653   He  -28500
......
......
```

Generally, there are several record for different samples in the order of testing routine.  And the data record for these samples are all in the same format.

#### My attempt

If there was just one sample in the datafile( in *.txt format), I can arrange the datafile into pandas. Dataframe, then I can handle the data with more analysis process in Python.

My code was shown here:

```
# Whole datafile with several samples record inside
with open("record.txt") as f:
     mylist = f.read().splitlines() 

## The record for each sample length in 803 lines
lines = mylist[0:803]

### The sample_name was extract from the third line
sample_name = lines[2]

### For each sample, the measure record was saved in several aspects, 
### which were regarded as some columns here
columns  = lines[22].split()

### Generate an empty columns for saving data record later.
df  = {columns[0][:-1]:[],columns[1][:-1]:[],columns[2][:-1]:[],columns[3][:-1]:[],columns[4][:-1]:[],
  columns[5][:-1]:[],columns[6][:-1]:[],} #### I only though about this dumb method for now

## Data extracting
### the valid data record of sample 1 was from line 23
for i in range(0, len(lines[23:]),1):
    for j in range(0, len(columns),1):
        df[columns[j][:-1]].append(lines[23+i].split()[j])
pd.DataFrame(df)
```

The result shows like this:

[image]

#### My target

From the code above, I could deal with datafile for one sample. But when there are several samples represented in the record text. I couldn't find a clue to deal with it efficiently.

Here is an illustration of my target. To generate an dataframe dict for saving all samples records.

[image]

Any advice would be appreciate!

Comment: Any advice on what? You already planned it very well, what is the problem?

Comment: I want to generate an dataframe.like variable contain all dataframes for each sample. Is this possible? For example, `Dataset` is a global dataset. When I called `Dataset[0]`, the Dataframe(Sample1) would appear.

Comment: Use a dictionary of dataframes or list of dataframes were elements are the sample datasets.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, mapping the dataframe into string list is the way to go? How to achieve that when we want to link an dataframe with a string?

Comment: Obviously it depends on what you're doing downstream, but you might consider just putting all the samples together into one dataframe and adding additional columns or indices that correspond to the sample number, sample name, and whatever other data you want. You could use `pd.concat` to build the dataframe up and then use `query` or indexing (`.loc`) to get the subsets. That way you're not restricted to working with one sample at a time. Pandas handles these large datasets quite well. But of course, it all depends on what you're doing next.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
# Whole datafile with several samples record inside
with open("record.txt",'r') as f:
     mylist = f.read().splitlines() 

dataset = []
while True:

    try:
        ## The record for each sample length in 803 lines
        lines, mylist = mylist[0:803], mylist[803:] #this split your list!!
        ### The sample_name was extract from the third line
        sample_name = lines[2]



        ### For each sample, the measure record was saved in several aspects, 
        ### which were regarded as some columns here
        columns  = lines[22].split()

        ### Generate an empty columns for saving data record later.
        df  = {columns[0][:-1]:[],columns[1][:-1]:[],columns[2][:-1]:[],columns[3][:-1]:[],columns[4][:-1]:[],
               columns[5][:-1]:[],columns[6][:-1]:[],} #### I only though about this dumb method for now

        ## Data extracting
        ### the valid data record of sample 1 was from line 23
        for i in range(0, len(lines[23:]),1):
            for j in range(0, len(columns),1):
                df[columns[j][:-1]].append(lines[23+i].split()[j])

    except IndexError:
        break

    df = pd.DataFrame(df)
    dataset.append(df)
```

Now `dataset[0]` should contain the df of Sample 1.

Comment: You can use a dictionary instead of a list if you prefer so.